# Why do ngIf with ng-content doesnt work to prevent init component

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, ng-template, ng-content

Ive got 2 tabs with the same component, and i need to initialize one of em according to active tab(ngIf on ng-template):

```
template: `
    <ng-template [ngIf]="active">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ng-template>
  `
```

But in case component inits twice, although it doesnt contain to DOM. Whats the problem? And how i can fix it to init it once.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gqratd?file=src

Comment: instead of active , declare a variable inside say for example "isActive" ts file and On init , change the value of that variable i.e., true or false . and update your template with *ngIf="isActive"  . If "isActive" will true than it will show template else not

Comment: @PushprajsinhChudasama ive done it in RadioTabComponent with @Input(), the problem is why it doesnt work as expected

Comment: @lesiano its sugared